# Sort array based on value ascending or descending php

Tags: php, arrays

my array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
)
```

start value is = 3

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 6
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 2
    )
```

any idea friends..

Comment: You have to use usort and write your own compare function. Have you tried that? And if so what does it look like?

Comment: what is your question here ?

Comment: here is the list of shoring functions in PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: [Sort it](http://php.net/sort). [Find position](http://php.net/array_search) of `3`. [Slice](http://php.net/array_slice) and [append](http://php.net/array_merge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$arr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if($v >= 3) 
   $a[] = $v;
  else
   $b[] = $v;
}
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
print_r($c);  //Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 0 [5] => 1 [6] => 2 )
```

Comment: Superb Rakesh Sharma ji

Answer (score 1):

**Step 0** (optional if needed):
order the array ([heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) or some other sort algorithm)

**Step 1:**
create an output array

**Step 2:**
loop trough the array and find your start point move the value and the ones after to new array and set the value in the original array to null

**Step 3:**
loop trough the array and move the remaining values over

DONE

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:
Call [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on the array.
Call [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search) to find the index you want to slice.
Call [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to cut off the part you want.
Call [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge) to merge them in the right order.

I don't know PHP that well but a quick look at php.net and I suspect this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how your array is already sorted and 0-indexed, you can just slice and reorganise it:

```
array_values(array_slice($arr, 3, null, true) + array_slice($arr, 0, 3, true));
```